# "Target Unreachable, identifier 'UserBean' resolved to null" in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jstl

I have a Java Class UserBean having Id and name two field .
when i am excuting jsp file on tomcatserver i am getting Two type of error randomly :

**1. Error Details :/AddUser.jsp(17,12) '#{UserBean.id}' Target Unreachable, identifier 'UserBean' resolved to null**

**2. /AddUser.jspNo saved view state could be found for the view identifier: /AddUser.jsp**

where i am doing wrong i dnt know ...

can any body help me out.

thanks 
Nikhil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is miss mapping faces-config.xml

try this ..
in faces-config.xml ,

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>UserBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.java.web.user.UserBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: hi .. problem is resolved. whether i have to use "UserBean" as mentioned in this managed-bean-name ? 
<managed-bean-name>UserBean</managed-bean-name>
Instance name or class name i should use for that.. ???

Comment: Yes class name is more suitable